# Subgroup of Z- Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $l(m,n)=${$am+bn|a,b\in\mathbb Z$} is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$
SO far I have 
Let $z_1,z_2 \in S$
Then $z_1= a_1m+b_1n$
     $z_2= a_2m+b_2n$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Did you mean $z_1=a_1m+b_1n$, and is $S=l(m,n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Check your notes for the definition of a subgroup. Once you have read the definition of a subgroup, you should try to convince yourself that (as a direct consequence of this definition) the statement "$\ell(m,n)$ forms a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$" means that

- For any two elements $z_1,z_2$ of $\ell(m,n)$, $z_1 + z_2 \in \ell(m,n)$,
- For any element $z \in \ell(m,n)$, $-z \in \ell(m,n)$.